# How can I create multiple panels in code and access them for events and such?

Tags: c#, winforms, panel

For a project I am doing, I'm trying to create 16 panels onto a WinForm, via two for loops. Then once those panels have been placed on the form loadup, I'm trying to have a MouseClick event for each panel. Only problem is accessing them. The panels are placed properly onto the winform, but I have no way of accessing them. I tried putting them into a List, but everytime I add them the list turns out to be empty. This is my code:

[image: Code For Panels]

Anyone have suggestions toward a solution?

Comment: @GrantWinney IMO, screenshots are so much more easier to handle, but I will take that into consideration next time

Comment: Did you try to use TableLayoutPanel and its facilities? IMO it was invented to manage this kind of situations.

Answer (score 0):

To start off, the list is always empty because it was declared static, I would guess that if you just made it a private member, then the list will work as expected (since you will be trying to access it outside of a static context).  In any case, I would do something like this:

Well, first thing's first, I would create a dictionary like this:

```
  Dictionary<string, Panel> formsPanels; // Initialize in form's constructors
```

Then, I would register each panel's mouse click event within the for loop(s) (i.e. panel.MouseClick += new EventHandler(eventMethod)), and assign each panel an unique name (I would use something like panel1, panel2, etc), then add that panel to the formsPanels using its name as the key.  Then within the event, you can query which panel was clicked using something like this:

```
  public void MouseClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      var panel = sender as Panel;
      if(panel == null) // check if the sender is a panel
         return;
      // Your Code
  }
```

I didn't verify any issues within my code, so I apologize for any errors that occur.  In any case, hope that helps.

Comment: Would not `clickedPanel` hold the same reference as the sender `panel`?

Comment: Yes, you're right, that is a redundant statement on my part, thanks for realizing that.